# How can a Magic Mouse work without bluetooth (nor cable)?

Tags: bluetooth, mouse

I just had a very strange experience: the bluetooth of my MacBook Pro (Retina mid-2015) was turned off, but the Magic Mouse was still working. I was able to move the mouse and click, however scrolling or special gestures didn't work (which is when I realised that the bluetooth was off).

After turning the bluetooth on and checking everything was working, I tried to reproduce the previous behaviour by turning the bluetooth off again. However, this time, I couldn't move or click.

Do you have an idea how this could have happened? Can the Magic Mouse use another communication channel as bluetooth? Or can it be that it still use the bluetooth even when it should be off?

It's not really important, but I'm dying to understand...

Edit 21.10.2022: I just had again the same experience, but with the Magic Keyboard (I could login with my password while the bluetooth was off). But this time the Magic Mouse wasn't connected.

Comment: How many devices do you have signed into iCloud in the wireless range of that Mac?

Comment: Good point, I have another MacBook (from my company) in the wireless range, even though it's not signed into iCloud. Maybe it still works that way.